# What is defined as a complex fold in map folding problem?

Tags: geometry

Today I came across the map folding problem, started thinking about a solution, and I came up with the following reasoning:
For a map with 3x3 squares, there are 4 different creases, two down and two across, each one can be folded in two ways, so for the initial folds we have 8 possibilities, then when we do this fold, we end up with 3 creases, and repeating the same logic, two, then one. So I supposed that the algorithm must be ((n-1)^2)!*2^((n-1)^2) in a nxn map(sorry I don't really know how to format the text), but for n=3, it gave me 384, while the true answer is 1368. I researched a bit, and found this article https://thatsmaths.com/2019/02/14/folding-maps-a-simple-but-unsolved-problem/
that talked about complex folds. I can't figure out what a complex fold is, can someone explain me/show an example?

Thanks in advance :)